# How to stop child component function running again after parent state changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components: App(parent) and AddToCart(child). In child component, I am adding child's whole state to localStorage; then I am calling a function in parent from the child's at the time of adding stuff to localStorage, which checks the localStorage items and change the state of the parent component. But, the problem is after the state of the parent change it is calling the child's function which is adding the same stuff twice to the localStorage.

I have tried to store the local storage data in parent's props, but it is not passing the prop value to an other child component.

Here is AddToCart component (child) code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

let cartItems = [];

export default class AddToCart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      one: ""
    };
  }

  updateCart = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        one: "some value"
      },
      () => {
        this.props.checkCart();
      }
    );
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.populateStorage();
    console.log("function is being called twice");
  }

  populateStorage = () => {
    cartItems.push(this.state);
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button className="btn btn--white" onClick={this.updateCart}>
           Add to cart
        </button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is App component (parent) code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import Header from "./components/layouts/Header";
import AddToCart from "./components/AddToCart";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { cartCount: 0 };
  }

  handleCartCount = cart => {
    let count = cart.length;
    this.setState({ cartCount: count });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkCart();
  }

  checkCart = () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("cart")) {
      let cartStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
      return this.handleCartCount(cartStorage);
    } else {
      console.log("Cart is empty!");
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header cartCount={this.state.cartCount} />
        <AddToCart checkCart={this.checkCart} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Is there any way to stop child component from updating again? Thanks.

Comment: What you're seeing is an ideal behaviour componentDidUpdate is not the right place to call populateStorage. It must be called inside callback of updateCart.

Comment: @VishalSharma comment is correct but putting my two cents in I should mention that when you use `componentDidUpdate` you almost always have to check if your props or state has been changed. You can read the doc on infinite loops and proper usage https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: You need to add condition on componentDidUpdate.This is not the right way to use componentDidUpdate(checking if values has changed or not). If you dont want to render the component with same props. Then use shouldComponentUpdate instead(https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate).

Comment: @VishalSharma It worked! I have moved the populateStorage to the updateCart method and got rid of componentDidUpdate()

Comment: @DebadiptiPatra I understand how it works but you may not need it always. If you need it, then what Shubham has mentioned is to be done.

Comment: @VishalSharma Does react re-renders child component after change in parent State?

Comment: @DebadiptiPatra yes, it does. If a change happens in parent state then child also re-renders.

Comment: @VishalSharma got it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't need the `componentDidUpdate()`. That will cause you to save an item as soon as your component first renders.

Rework your component to use this.populateStorage() in the call-back after you setState from `updateCart()`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

let cartItems = [];

Here's the sandbox for reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/black-sun-i4omf

    export default class AddToCart extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          one: ""
        };
      }

      updateCart = () => {
        this.setState(
          {
            one: "some value"
          },
          () => {
            this.populateStorage();
          }
        );
      };


      populateStorage = () => {
        cartItems.push(this.state);
        console.log(cartItems);
        localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <button className="btn btn--white" onClick={this.updateCart}>
              Add to cart
            </button>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: this is the same thing I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: Yup.. I got rid of componentDidUpdate() and moved populateStorage() to updateCart() callback. And it worked! Thanks!